# Installation will resume automatically of calyx os from mi a2

Tags: custom-rom

Device boots to fastboot screen
Installation does not resume automatically
Please find below logs of device-flasher.exe

```
Android Factory Image Flasher version 1.0.3
Extracting jasmine_sprout-factory-2.6.1.zip
Verifying platform-tools_r29.0.6-windows.zip
Extracting platform-tools_r29.0.6-windows.zip
1. Connect to a wifi network and ensure that no SIM cards are installed
2. Enable Developer Options on device (Settings -> About Phone -> tap "Build number" 7 times)
3. Enable USB debugging on device (Settings -> System -> Advanced -> Developer Options) and allow the computer to debug (hit "OK" on the popup when USB is connected)
4. Enable OEM Unlocking (in the same Developer Options menu)

Press ENTER to continue

Detected jasmine_sprout 4a5a3f6

Devices to be flashed:
jasmine_sprout 4a5a3f6

Press ENTER to continue
Unlocking jasmine_sprout 4a5a3f6 bootloader...
5. Please use the volume and power keys on the device to unlock the bootloader

  5a. Once jasmine_sprout 4a5a3f6 boots, disconnect its cable and power it off
  5b. Then, press volume down + power to boot it into fastboot mode, and connect the cable again.
The installation will resume automatically
```

Instructions are at [link](https://calyxos.org/get/install/)

Answer (score 0):

Need to install bootloader interface drivers on Windows operating system from [link](https://www.droidwin.com/install-google-android-bootloader-interface-drivers)

Alternative resolution is to complete instruction with operating systems MacOS and Linux.
On MacOS, ensure

1 archiving downloaded and extracted folder to its original an archive with its original name, and

2 extracting to a folder with name similar to archive name since extracting happens to a folder with different name